# Python matplotlib graph problem

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as PL

matplotlib.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
PL.loglog(a, b,'o')
ax.set_title('Graph Example')
plt.show()
```

1) This displays the graph with points on the plot. Is there a way to join these points with a smooth curve.

2) I want to draw more than one plot in the same graph(i.e. for a different set of values of lists a and b) . How do I do that? I want to represent points of each graph with a different symbol(cross,square,circle) or color.

Comment: By "smooth line" do you mean interpolation as in Bezier or simple drawing lines from point to point? The latter is done by "PL.loglog(a, b, '-')", as you can see here: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See @Ber's comment
2. Simply call `PL.loglog` multiple times.